# Mediawiki search external database - prepend hook

Tags: php, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I am attempting to write a plugin that displays both the internal mediawiki DB results and results from an external SQL database based on the search term supplied.

I have written all of the search code, but I am struggling to actually display my results. I have checked Special: Version and my extension appears.

I have tried this hook:

```
$wgHooks[ 'SpecialSearchResultsPrepend'][] = 'onSpecialSearchResultsPrepend';
```

Where my function is

```
function onSpecialSearchResultsPrepend($t, $out, $term){
    some routine
}
```

, yet I am unable to correctly display anything on this hook.  Furthermore, when I just try to write to the debug console or print raw debug text, I get no output from my extension.

The mediawiki documentation specifies to return false in order to disable the generic search output.  I have tried this to just verify that I am actually hooked correctly, and returning false from the hook does not disable search results.  Therefore, I believe I am using an incorrect method for hooking.

What is the proper way to hook into this function?  I have tried in separate files, global functions, or declared within classes.  None have seemed to correct my problem.  Right now, I am attempting to just return false from the main extension file, ie 'externalsqlsearch.php'.

Comment: Basic example that works for me if put in LocalSettings.php:
$wgHooks[ 'SpecialSearchResultsPrepend'][] = function( $specialSearch, OutputPage $out ) {
 $out->addWikiText( 'MaxSem was here!' );
 return false;
};

Are you sure you're registering it properly and you're using $out for output as opposed to echo()?

Comment: Thanks Max.  That simple example worked.  However, what I ultimately need to do is move this hook call into the extension file itself.  For some reason, whenever I do that, the extension is loaded, but the hook is not registered. I found $wgSpecialVersionShowHooks and set that to true, so now I can at least see if my hook is registered or not.

Comment: Got it working.  You have to register hooks via extensions.json.  See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my working solution for Mediawiki 1.26.2 - I was unable to find this in the documentation, but I was able to glean it from reading other extensions.

To register a hook, you must declare it in the extensions.json file under the 'hooks' section.  For me, this looked like

```
"AutoloadClasses": {
    "ExternalSQLSearchHooks": "ExternalSQLSearch.hooks.php"
},

"Hooks": {
        "SpecialSearchResultsPrepend": [
            "ExternalSQLSearchHooks::onSpecialSearchResultsPrepend"
        ] 
},
```

and in ExternalSQLSearch.hooks.php, the barebones example:

```
class ExternalSQLSearchHooks {

    public static function onSpecialSearchResultsPrepend($t, $out, $term){
        $out->addWikiText( 'Testing');
        return true;
    }

}
```